# Perfect recall assumption

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, dynamic-games, extensive-games

When we assume that the players can recall perfectly everything about the previous stages of a game, in essence we assume that they know the history path that they followed until they reached to some point of the game. For example if we have a game with signals and actions played based on these signals, then the history can be of the form $h_{i,t}=(a_{i,t},s_{i,t})_{t=1}^T$ where $a_{i,t}$ are the past actions that player $i$ has played until time period $t$ and $s_{i,t}$ the signals that player $i$ received until time $t$. Every other player $j \neq i$ has a history that she recalls and $h_t=(h_{i,t},h_{-i,t})$ denotes the profile of past histories of all the players. My question is the following:

Assuming perfect recall, means that every player $i$ remembers only her own history $h_{i,t}$ or that after each round the players somehow reveal their past actions and signals and all of them will know at $T+1$, the profile of histories $h_{T+1}=(h_{i,T},h_{-i,T})$?

Answer (score 1):

Perfect recall means that every player remembers her own history.

Comment: ok...and something else....perfect recall is the same as perfect monitoring?

Comment: Please post new questions as new questions.

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/48556/perfect-recall-vs-perfect-monitoring happy?