# Perfect recall vs perfect monitoring

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, dynamic-games, extensive-games

Following my previous previous post [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/48554/perfect-recall-assumption/48555#48555), I would like to add another question. Is perfect recall the same with perfect monitoring? If not, what are their differences?

Comment: What is the context of the question? Usually, the term "perfect monitoring" is used in the context of repeated games or stochastic games.